# ADB push command is case-insensitive

Tags: android, shell, adb, push

I have a file named **example.JSON** and I am trying it to push it in `/system/data` directory on an Android phone

```
adb push example.json /system/data
```

After the successfully push in the `/system/data` directory I see the file extension changes from **example.JSON** to **example.json**

But I want `adb` to raise an error instead of pushing the file anyways, since the case of the filename is different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your OS's filesystem might be case-insensitive ([although Android certainly isn't](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/57334/19250)). So this might not be a problem with ADB after all, and instead with your OS simply passing it the file.

If you want to retain the exact case of the file on the android device, you can specify the full path:

```
adb push example.json /system/data/example.JSON
```